# Rust application using GTK3 compiles without errors but run give error msg

Tags: rust, gtk3

I have a small application that if I do a println!("Hello World"); compiles and runs properly.  If I change the source to

```
...
        let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("com.xyz_Portfolio_Tracker")
        .build();
...
```

This code in GTK3 will compile but give the following error message when you run the app.

```
        error: process didn't exit successfully:
        target\debug\xyz_tracker.exe (exit
        code:0xc0000139, STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND)
```

Based on research the error message supposedly points to a missing "dll".  Anybody have any idea of how to find out what is missing or has solved this before.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the RUST compiler searches the windows path for the .lib .  I had an application that had the needed .lib but of a lower version higher up in the path.  Once i moved the application down in the path structure the application I was building ran.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by John is correct in spirit, but lacks details that would make the answer as helpful as could be and since this is one of the 2 results for the Google search related to the issue at hand, I thought I should add some details for anyone else who comes across the issue.

Ultimately, for me, the issue ended up being that there was a `harfbuzz.dll` file located in a directory that was in the system-wide `PATH` environment variable while the `MSVC` built `gtk4` version of `harfbuzz.dll` was in a directory that was in the user-specific `PATH` variable.

Here are some more bits of information that I put together while working on this issue that may help others track down the root cause of their related issues:

- Running the built GTK `.exe` within a `powershell` or `cmd` prompt will produce output similar to what is shown in the original question, but if you locate the program in Explorer and run it with a double-click, an error window will pop up and give a name of a `.dll` and the name of the missing entry point function that is being looked for
- I was able to find which `.dll` was the offending file by using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer%27s) "DLL" tab which shows the dynamically linked libraries for every running process as well as their location in the file system. I also ran across a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Ep0chalypse/0e0f9ef43eb7f0218eaa8fe0822f3d36) that suggested `listdlls64.exe` from the same software suite
- That [same Gist](https://gist.github.com/Ep0chalypse/0e0f9ef43eb7f0218eaa8fe0822f3d36) has some more information regarding this issue
- [These are the DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTOGL.png) and their location that were supposed to be loaded from the GTK4 build (for my basic hello world application) including the `harfbuzz.dll` that was loaded from the incorrect location
- [These are the DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PxFT.png) and their locations that are Windows specific and not related (at least in my case, and I would assume in general for this specific issue) to the issue at hand
- From the collection of posts that I have found related to this issue including the previously linked Gist, the Microsoft specific Java Hotspot install's `harfbuzz.dll` seems to be a main culprit. So, check if either of your `PATH` environment variables contain an entry that points to something like `C:\...\jdk-<version numbers>-hotspot\bin` and either remove the entry or move the `c:\gtk-build\gtk\<arch>\release\bin` entry to a higher priority than the Java Hotspot path